# Inserting rows from one multimillion rows table to another

Tags: postgresql

I have a transactional (OLTP) database with tables that have about 100 million rows. I have on another server a data warehouse with similar size tables. I would like to update the data warehouse close to real time.
Data is entered into the transactional database at a rate of thousands of rows within minutes by thousands of users. 
I wonder if using a trigger to insert, possibly into a staging database on the same server where the transactional database resides is a good option that will not hit performance of the transactional database.
Or, should I use an ETL process?
Is using CSV files a preferred (faster, less load on the source database) approach, compared to inserting into database tables?
Any other ideas?
Thank you very much.